# Image gray scale with animation - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-image

I have a slider with value. When I change the slider I want the image in imageview to become gray scaled based on the value set in slider.

Comment: Provide a code you are using so we can help.

Comment: Have you tried anything or just demanding for code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you would need to set the image as a property in the view controller, to say myImage for this example.

You also need to create a value changed action for the slider.

Inside the `UISlider` value changed method, you could use the following:

```
float sliderValue = VALUE OF SLIDER BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0

self.myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sliderValue], @"inputColor", [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]], nil].outputImage];
```

This changes the level of monochrome depending on the slider value.

Which uses the `CIFilter` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIFilter/filterWithName:keysAndValues:

And the monochrome filter: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMonochrome